# Java Applet runs without a main method?

Tags: java, applet, program-entry-point

I was running a Java class that `extends Applet implements Runnable` and apparently the program can run, but there is no `main` method. I thought Java applications needs the `main` method as its entry point?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do applets not need a main()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932052/why-do-applets-not-need-a-main)

Answer (score 8):

Java Applets have an init method instead of main.
It's:

```
public void init() {... }
```

Comment: Oh okay so applets use init and applications uses main. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but applets aren't applications. There *is* a main method in the applet runner (assuming it's implemented in Java; it need not be) but the applet doesn't work that way; it gets loaded/instantiated from a file and then it proceeds along its lifecycle through [initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#init--), [starting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#start--), operating, [stopping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#stop--), and finally being [destroyed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#destroy--). The code that sends it through these states is hidden from the applet's view; it just knows its in an [environment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html) that can run applets.

Answer (score 2):

Applets differ from stand-alone Java applications in that they do not need to implement a main method.

[Life Cycle of an Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/lifeCycle.html)

Answer (score 0):

*Copied from google results:*

Applets are standalone programs which require a third party tool for its execution that is either it is java enabled web browser or applet runner. So it doesn't have main(). It is 
possible to run a program without main.

Possible duplicate of:
[Why do applets not need a main()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932052/why-do-applets-not-need-a-main)